# Apache log format: repeat headers

Tags: logging, apache-2.4

The [`LogFormat`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html) directive allows you to set a custom format for your log files, including any headers you're interested in, such as:

```
\"%{Referer}i\" \"%{Location}o\"
```

However, some headers may be used more than once in a single HTTP request:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
```

Apache only outputs the first of these headers in the log. Is there any way of logging out *all* of the values?

Comment: maybe you can change it for `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` ? ;)

Comment: That was just one example, there are other headers like `Authorization` that may be repeated. Even if merging them is the answer, before you can change them you need to find them, hence the desire to log them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it dynamically with default Apache log configuration, you have to use `mod_log_forensic` : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_log_forensic.html

Comment: Are there any good tools for reading `mod_log_forensic` output?

Comment: It appears that `mod_log_forensic` only shows the full request headers, not the response headers.

Comment: Even Apache default logs are logging request infos, then check this http://serverfault.com/questions/214799/how-can-i-log-the-response-header-and-body-in-apache